# I cannot see the "List" in the "Apps you can Add "?

Tags: list, list-view, custom-list

I cannot see the Custom List in app you can Add . But i have to add a list. So how can i do this?

[image]

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online? check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-list-in-sharepoint-0d397414-d95f-41eb-addd-5e6eff41b083) documentation. let me know if it helps you.

Comment: I am not using Sharepoint Online. But this doesn't work. I still only see the same apps in the picture. Also i cannot add any documanet library too.

Comment: Actually this is a subsite. And in the main site i can see whatever i want to add. But Subsite is not showing Custom lisr, Document Library .. in Apps You can Add Section.

Comment: I found the right answer. I compared main site and subsite Site Features. And I saw Team Collabaration Lists is deactivated on my subsite. I turn it on. And I saw all apps i can add.

Answer (score 1):

I found the right answer. I compared main site and subsite Site Features. And I saw Team Collabaration Lists is deactivated on my subsite. I turn it on. And I saw all apps i can add.

Comment: Glad you found it. Mark it as an answer!